# Within XY minutes of the start

Tags: meaning-in-context

I misunderstood the following: "An existing booking can be changed once, depending on the availability, but only **within 60 minutes of the scheduled start time**." The scheduled time was 9:30 AM and the changes were accepted **no later than 8:30 AM (or before)**. My understanding was that the booking can be changed **between 8:30 and 9:30 AM**, so within 60 minutes (before the start).

Any help/feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Related: [Interpret the phrase "within a month of the first Sunday in June"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447899).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Within 60 minutes of the scheduled start time" means during the 60 minutes immediately before the start time, or - depending on context - during the 60 minutes immediately after the start time.

"An existing booking can be changed once, depending on the availability, but only within 60 minutes of the scheduled start time" means the booking can only be changed during the 60 minutes immediately before the start time.

Of course, that is the opposite of normal booking conditions which don't allow last-minute changes, so in my opinion whoever wrote that condition made a mistake - they've accidentally said the opposite of what they meant.

Comment: Quite true. It the text was limited to `within 60 minutes of the scheduled start time.` , it  actually suggests the booking can be changed till 10:30 (if the flight was at 9:30) .   Though one would  understand  that no alteration would be possible after the boarding time, it's definitely not worded with due care.

Comment: Yes, they probably meant *up to 60* minutes.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments! I am not a native speaker and your comments helped me a lot. I have just shared it with the organization, which has this misleading wording on their voucher. Actually, it is a museum in Europe visited by 20000 people daily. I hope they will improve it :)